# Display.displays.Length is count "2". But multiple monitor doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine, display, multiple-monitors

I have some problem.

**First, my computer environment is below:**

1. OS: MacOS (Macbook pro 2015)
2. Unity3D veresion: 2019.1.6f1 Personal
3. Secondary monitor: LG monitor (This is connected HDMI from Macbook)

**Second, I setting up unity project below:**

1. Display Resolution Dialog: Enabled
2. Camera(1) Target Display: Display 1
3. Camera(2) Target Display: Display 2

**Third, I had wrote some code below:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DualMonitor : MonoBehaviour {
       public Camera camera1, camera2;
       public Text myText;

       void Start() {
            for (int i = 0; i < Display.displays.Length; i++) {
               Display.displays[i].Activate(Display.displays[i].systemWidth, Display.displays[i].systemHeight, 60);
            }

            // if (Display.displays.Length > 1)
            //    Display.displays[1].Activate(Display.displays[1].systemWidth, Display.displays[1].systemHeight, 60);

            myText.text = (Display.displays.Length).ToString();
            Debug.Log("Display connected: " + Display.displays.Length);
       }
}
```

So, I had build and run in my computer. "Display.displays.Length" text value is "2".

My macbook monitor is shown, but my secondary monitor (LG monitor) is not show anything. I don't know.

**[My macbook display]**

[image]

**[LG Monitor display]**

Only the monitor wallpaper is visible.

***How can I this problem solve..?***

***To be precise, I want to know how it runs on Mac OS. (I confirmed that it runs normally in Windows OS.)***

I'd really appreciate it if you let me know.

Regards.

Comment: Please include your code as text.

Comment: @MichielLeegwater Hi, I have include my source code.

Comment: What happens if you uncomment the lines `// camera1.targetDisplay = 1;
            // camera2.targetDisplay = 2;` again?

Comment: @derHugo Hi, I was trying to set a target display on each camera with source code. But I think that code is wrong and I deleted it from the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each screen needs it's own camera, in the camera settings you can set which screen it renders to[image]

So in your case, you need 2 camera's. Camera 1 with target display 1 and Camera 2 with target display 2

Comment: Hi, Steven Delrue :D! I've already specified different display values for each camera, as you said.

Comment: did you test without passing with, height and refresh rate in the Activate method? Like this :  `for (int i = 0; i < Display.displays.Length; i++)
        {
            Display.displays[i].Activate();
        }`

Comment: Can you try with just `.Activate()` ? Maybe settings the refresh rate fixed to 60 causes the problem.

Comment: I have update some code, as you said. Like this: for (int i = 0; i < Display.displays.Length; i++) { Display.displays[i].Activate(); }

Comment: But I have same problem. I can still see the screen on my MacBook, but only the desktop on my LG monitor. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do the 2 monitors show up in the Display Resolution Dialog ?

Comment: No. Only showing "Screen resolution" and "Quality" and "Graphics device to use". The resolution values are different when running build files on a MacBook and when running on an LG monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem solved not well. But I have another solution this problem.

**I had used Windows 10 with Parallels.** Parallels is Mac OS application for virtualization.

So, my source code above worked fine and dual-monitor function was executed.

I have not find solution for original problem yet. I'll find solution for original problem. Maybe I find some information, I'll post new post for solution.

***Finally, my problem temporary solution summary below:***

1. Install Parallels applications.
2. Install Windows 10.
3. Create new Unity3D project and add two cameras.
4. Setting up each camera "Target Display".
5. Create new script file and write source code above.
6. Build for Windows (x86 or x86_64)
7. Run and testing

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.